# joda DateTimeFormatter fails with literal 0 in format

Tags: java, parsing, numbers, jodatime, literals

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter DF_YYYY_0MM_DD = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy0MMdd");
        System.out.println(DF_YYYY_0MM_DD.parseLocalDate("201800101"));
    }

}
```

expect the above to return a date 2018-01-01. But get Exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "201800101" is too short
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:900)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate(DateTimeFormatter.java:844)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a single quote per the [docs](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

`DateTimeFormatter DF_YYYY_0MM_DD = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy'0'MMdd");`

Although weirdly enough, in my testing it still doesn't work, due to what seems like a bug in the library - basically `isNumericToken(String token)` in joda's `DateTimeFormat` doesn't take numeric literals into account. This ultimately results in joda expecting 9 digits for year instead of 4.

So as a workaround, you can do this to build the formatter (rather than create it from string pattern directly):

```
DateTimeFormatter DF_YYYY_0MM_DD = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendYear(4,4).appendLiteral("0").appendMonthOfYear(2).appendDayOfMonth(2).toFormatter();
```

Or, prefix your date with 5 zeros (so that year now has 9 digits).

```
DateTimeFormatter DF_YYYY_0MM_DD = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy'0'MMdd");
System.out.println(DF_YYYY_0MM_DD.parseLocalDate("00000201800101"));
```

Or use a separator.

```
DateTimeFormatter DF_YYYY_0MM_DD = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-0-MM-dd");
System.out.println(DF_YYYY_0MM_DD.parseLocalDate("2018-0-01-01"));
```

Comment: Thanks Vasan, just wanted to confirm. I think that first option is the best solution in this case.
    `DateTimeFormatter DF_YYYY_0MM_DD = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendYear(4,4).appendLiteral("0").appendMonthOfYear(2).appendDayOfMonth(2).toFormatter();`

Comment: Yes, it's the cleanest. Unless you have a restriction like pattern is coming in from elsewhere you cannot control, you can go with this.